How to set the value of a Power Apps canvas form field based on the corresponding field from a SharePoint list
I have a SharePoint list containing several employee demographic information columns, including two lookup columns from another list containing EmployeeID and EmployeeFullName columns.  I created a Canvas form, linked my "Leave of Absence" SharePoint site, and inserted EditForm.  All of my fields populate correctly, and the EmployeeID and EmployeeFullName display a drop-down of all the choices.
When users complete new forms, I want them to select the EmployeeFullName from the drop-down and I want the EmployeeID to populate (read-only) automatically.  I have tried to format the EmployeeID to do this to no avail.  When I type formulas, it seems only to display DataCardValue# and EmployeeID_DataCard1 which are not accepted.
I tried setting the default value:
LookUp(YourSharePointList, EmployeeFullName.Value = EmployeeFullName_DataCard1.Selected.Value, EmployeeID)


Try replacing EmployeeFullName_DataCard1 with the name of drop-down inside this data card
